# Sympy package/ nsolve function in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, matrix, sympy

I am working with non-linear equations and am trying to solve them through Python. Regarding this nsolve function, why does it only return one pair of solutions?

```
import math
import sympy
from sympy import Symbol, nsolve
    
a = Symbol('a')
b = Symbol('b')

nsolve((a*b + 2*b - 675, a - 2*b - 1), (a,b), (0,0))
```

**Output:**

[36.2729520163938, 17.6364760081969]

**Expected Output:**

[36.2729520163938, 17.6364760081969]

[36.2729520163938, -19.136476.............]

Comment: As a numerical solver it will always return only one solution. You can use a different starting point e.g. `(0, -1)` to get a different solution.

Comment: You can also call sympy's symbolic solver `solve((a * b + 2 * b - 675, a - 2 * b - 1), (a, b))`,  and then call `evalf()` on all elements of its output.